# не удаётся отсортировать массив java

Tags: java

есть некий двухмерный массив, необходимо сортировать его по значениям последнего столбца, выдаёт ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:614)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
```

Как исправить данную ошибку?

```
public void sortr(String[][] args){
          for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
              String [] zamena = new String[3];
              if ((Integer.parseInt(args[i][2])) > (Integer.parseInt(args[i+1][2]))){
                  zamena[0] = args[i][0];
                  zamena[1] = args[i][1];
                  zamena[2] = args[i][2];
                  args[i][0]=args[i+1][0];
                  args[i][1]=args[i+1][1];
                  args[i][2]=args[i+1][2];
                  args[i+1][0]=zamena[0];
                  args[i+1][1]=zamena[1];
                  args[i+1][2]=zamena[2];
              }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Если понятен текст ошибки, то должно быть и понятно, как исправить. Какой размер массива?

Comment: Размер массива 8 строк, 3 столбца

Comment: Значит где-то вместо числа лежит ничего.

Comment: Это может быть из за того что я еще не заполнил полностью массив, а только частично, где ничего нет там null?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно.

Comment: большое спасибо , сейчас попробую

Comment: А в чём может быть неправильность самого алгоритма, почему не правильно сортирует?